# Angular2 child components [ngclass] styles applied with delay

Tags: css, angular, components

please advice on this issue:

Lets say I have a parent component that displays a child component which is a loading icon with overlay:

```
 <loading [FullOverlay]="true"></loading>
```

I pass in a value for the overlay class type, and depending on the value for **FullOverlay**, the child component will use one of 2 class styles using **[nglcass]**.

The problem is that for a split second there are no styles applied at all on the child component, how can I fix this delay?

The child components html:

```
<div [ngClass]="FullOverlay ? 'full-overlay' : 'small-overlay'">
  <img src="assets/images/loading.gif" class="loading-icon-size" alt="loading">
</div>
```

Child component ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'loading',
  templateUrl: './loading.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loading.component.scss']
})

export class LoadingComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() FullOverlay: boolean;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you solve this issue?